# Scrapy: extract data-mspid value in HTML

Tags: python, scrapy

How do I scrape the value of data-mspid and the HTML code on the webpage using Scrapy?

Following is the HTML code:

```
<h1 itemprop="name" class="prdct-dtl__ttl" **data-mspid="13231"**> Something </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```
data = response.xpath("//h1[@itemprop='name']/@data-mspid").extract_first()
```